# How to submit one out of many forms to seperate tables in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Here is my existing code:

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['submitForm'])) { 

    print_r($_POST);

     }

?>
<form action="" name="form1" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm" />
</form>

<form action="" name="form2" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm" />
</form>

<form action="" name="form3" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm" />
</form>
```

This simply posts any of the forms which are submitted, individually.

What I'm trying to accomplish is submitting these individual forms to a specific table in the same database.

So for example, Form1 would be submitted to Table1, Form2 to Table2, etc. Each form will always be submitted to it's matching table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **name** foreach of your Submit input form element, for example to submitForm1, submitForm2 and submitForm3, like:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm1" />

<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm2" />

<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm3" />
```

Then in your php logic you could do something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitForm1'])){
    // Do things with your form1

}elseif(isset($_POST['submitForm2'])){
    // Do things with your form2

}elseif(isset($_POST['submitForm3'])){
    // Do things with your form3

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the $_POST or $_GET array is composite of your input tag. So when you call $_POST['submitForm'] you should have an input with that name like

```
 <input name ='sumbitform' />
```

If you need to get separate form just change your code in this way:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submitForm1'])) { 

 //sql statement for table 1 there

     }

if (isset($_POST['submitForm2'])) { 

    //sql statement for table 2 there

     }

if (isset($_POST['submitForm3'])) { 

    //sql statement for table 3 there

     }

?>
<form action="" name="form1" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm1" />
</form>

<form action="" name="form2" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm2" />
</form>

<form action="" name="form3" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm3" />
</form>
```